# Can you explain what EXACTLY happens when you multiply $\sigma^2$ to $N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I understand that when you apply a transformation $\sigma Y+\mu$ to $Y$~$N(0,1)$ ,we get a new random variable that is distributed $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. However, I dont know through which mechanism this was obtained. Is it by multiplying the pdf by $\sigma^2$ and adding $\mu$? In general, I usually think about it as the following for normal distribution manipulations:

If you multiply, leave the mean alone but square the variance

If you add, leave the variance alone but add to the mean.

Is there another way of thinking about normal manipulations? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not multiplying or adding the pdf, you're multiplying and adding the random variable.  And "leave the mean alone but square the variance" is wrong.
the basic principles for linear transformation of the mean and variance are:

- Multiplying the random variable by a constant $\alpha$ multiplies the mean by $\alpha$ and the variance by $\alpha^2$.
- Adding a constant $\beta$ to the random variable adds $\beta$ to the mean and leaves the variance unchanged.

So if $Y$ is any random variable of mean $0$ and variance $1$, $\sigma Y + \mu$ will have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Now, why is this still normal?  Well, for this, you might want to look at the pdf.  If $f(x)$ is the pdf of random variable $X$, the pdf of $\alpha X + \beta$ (for $\alpha > 0$) is $\alpha^{-1} f((x-\beta)/\alpha)$